# Amazon EC2 multiple domains

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, dns

I have a windows server 2012 r2 and would like to host multiple domains with different sites, for example www.domain1.com.br, www.domain2.com.br, teste.domain1.com, ...

I'm having trouble because the DNS www.registro.br only accepts IP entries only with port 80 by default. My amazon ec2 only releases a public IP for that. How can I configure my IIS to accept these multiple sites? I searched the Internet and found quite the VPC amazon but was not used for this purpose.

What should I do?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/06/18/bind-multiple-sites-on-same-ip-address-and-port-in-ssl.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can point all your sites to the same single IP. In the 'bindings' section of the IIS manager, you tell each site you have setup, what domain to answer for...its really quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Tcp rules in the security group with another port and set the firewall settings to allow port connection from 81 or any port of your choice. Check this out http://techcerberus.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-host-multiple-website-on-amazon.html